# Create dictionaries of unpredictable data in Python

Tags: python

I wrote a python script that lists all the AWS instances in an AWS account. It gives you the public and private IP, with some other information.

But it fails when there are multiple nested public and private IPs in the json. I need to be able to report all public and private IPs.

I am new to Python. And I need to know how I can build dictionaries of the data, if the contents of the data is unpredictable.

For example, some instances can have as little as a few private IPs or as many as 10 or 20 of them. Same with public IPs.

This is what the data looks like: [AWS Instance IPs](https://pastebin.com/Tq3Evp8T)

This what my code looks like so far:

```
import boto3
import time
aws_account='company-prod'
session = boto3.Session(profile_name=aws_account)
ec2 = session.client("ec2")
instance_list = ec2.describe_instances()
for reservation in instance_list["Reservations"]:
        for instance in reservation.get("Instances", []):
.... print out info about the instance....
```

Full code to my script can be found here: [AWS List Instances](https://pastebin.com/DnpwFTtD)

How can I build dictionaries of this data if the data varies from instance to instance?

Comment: You stated that you have a `.json` with the data correct? If so you can just use the `json` module. I can post code of how to do so if you'd like

Comment: Yes that's right. The AWS commands output in json. I would certainly appreciate a code example if you could. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## To read/write a .json in Python

Reading data into Python:

```
with open('inputs.json', 'r') as file: # 'r' for read-only
    my_variable = json.load(file)
```

Writing data into json:

```
with open('outputs.json', 'w') as f: # 'w' for write 'w+' will create a file if not found
    json.dump(my_variable, f)
```

I imagine that when you properly load your .json file it will be easily accessed by standard Python indexing via `[]` (this is syntax is used to index lists, dictionaries, and tuples, but when indexing dictionaries you should put a key instead of an index -> ['potatoes'] instead of [0])